# Simple-Form input :collection does not highlight field when error is raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with simple form it doesn’t highlight field where error is raised.

**search_controller.rb**

```
    class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_search, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  layout 'admin'

  def index
    @searches = Search.includes(:brand, :search_index, :price_ranges)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(search_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @search.save
        format.html { redirect_to @search, notice: 'Search was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @search }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @search.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @search.update(search_params)
        format.html { redirect_to searches_url, notice: 'Search was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @search }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @search.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @search.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to searches_url, notice: 'Search was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_search
      @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    end

    def search_params
      params.require(:search).permit(:brand_id)
    end
end
```

**search.rb**

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base    
validates_presence_of :brand
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@search) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :brand_id, collection: Brand.all.order(:name), prompt: 'Select brand' %>
 <% end %>
```

[image]
I want brand field be hihlighted the same way keywords field is. 
I've checked if **validates_presence_of brand** raise the error and it dose, but doesn’t highlight the field.

Comment: Show us the view code and a related controller please.

Comment: Can someone help with this?

Comment: Show the code for the entire form since the keywords validation IS working. Also where is the keywords validation taking place? That should answer your question.